# Full width image carousel that can center selected image and partially show other images in gallery

Tags: javascript, image, gallery, slide

I've looked for a plugin that will do this and the closest I could find was CarouselLite but it doesn't really do what I am trying to get. Most of other libraries I could find don't like 100% width or hide inactive images or don't center the active image scrolling it to the very left of the gallery div. I'm not really good at javascipt, maybe someone could point me to a library that will work for me.

I am trying to set a full width image gallery to show fairly large images the way that selected (by a mouse click) image is centered on the page whilst other images are partially shown as well (as much as the screen width allows). Clicking this same image again will center next one on the screen (slide effect would be lovely), clicking other images should center one that's been clicked.

It sounds quite simple and I was expecting to find something that does this quickly. Spent two days with no luck. I hope someone has came across a library that will do this.

Here is a [small image](http://abolotnov.jino.ru/carousel_sample.jpg) demonstrating what I am looking for (imagine, it's 100% width):

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to get somewhat working at least somehow [here](http://abolotnov.jino.ru/test.html) with prototype UI and carousel plugin. The problem here is that it still aligns the active image to the left side of the screen whilst I am trying to center it.

Comment: Link is dead... not very helpful.